# Is it possible to capture Audit information on User management actitivy in Tridion

Tags: 2011, core-service, event-system, user-management

One of the client need Audit Information on all user management activity.

1. User Creation
2. Group Creation
3. Change the Permisssion an Rights for User or Group
4. Assign User to different Group
5. Add USer to different Group
6. Delete the User

I know we don't have history of user management.

Current version is Tridion 2011 SP1, planning to upgrade to Web 8.

Let us know if we need to have our own extension to capture the required audit information.

Answer (score 3):

All of these actions will trigger events in the backend. It would be relatively simple to write an event that captures it and writes it *somewhere* like a database.

Here's a good starting point: https://github.com/NunoLinhares/tridion-2011-reporting/tree/master/Tridion.Extensions.Reporting

Comment: Thanks Nuno do we have anything out of the box on new release or in future release of tridion to have audit of user management

Comment: Not currently, and future releases won't solve your problem today :)